# AMPL IDE: unable to use lpsolve

Tags: linear-programming, ampl, lpsolve

I downloaded and extracted `amplide-demo-linux64.tar.gz` to `/opt/amplide/`.

Then I downloaded `lp_solve_5.5.2.0_exe_ux32.tar.gz` and extracted file `lpsolve` to `/opt/amplide/ampl/`.

And I have `liblpsolve55.so` under directory suggested on AMPL page:

```
kjrz@kjrz-tsh ~ $ ll /usr/lib/lp_solve/
total 604
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root   4096 Jun 24  2014 .
drwxr-xr-x 185 root root  20480 Jan 14 11:11 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 590168 Dec 23  2013 liblpsolve55.so
```

This is what happens:

```
ampl: option solver lpsolve; 
ampl: model owd.mod;
ampl: data owd.dat;
ampl: solve;
lpsolve: error while loading shared libraries: liblpsolve55.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
exit code 127
<BREAK>
```

How is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put (a link to) the `liblpsolve55.so` somewhere on the library search paths, for example `/usr/lib`:

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/lp_solve/liblpsolve55.so /usr/lib
```

Also make sure that you have 32-bit (x86) version of `liblpsolve55.so` installed. For example, on 64-bit Ubuntu you can install 32-bit version of `liblpsolve55.so` as follows:

```
$ sudo apt-get install lp-solve:i386
```